# Cannot Map the input Column,because the datatype doesnt match

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

When I tried to match the lookup columns inside the lookup shape I get the mentioned error in SSIS 2012 version.

I checked and corrected the data types in the source and the destination but till the error occurs. How can I match the columns for this case.

Can someone help ?

Comment: Not sure what triggers a meta data refresh on a lookup shape but this is what you need.  Worst case, drop and recreate the task.

Comment: I tried it but still having the same issue. Is there any better idea ?